# How to split these products to packages?

Tags: algorithm

I have this group of products:

```
Product     Quantity    Weight Per Unit
pro#1          7               5kg
pro#2          5               5kg
```

I want to split these products into packages, but the max weight of the package is 22kg.

Let's assume that I have that table in array, I want an algorithm to solve this problem.

This is what I tried so far.

```
$products = array(
    array('weight'=> 5, 'quantity' => 7),
    array('weight'=> 5, 'quantity' => 5),
);
$max_weight = 22;
$packs = array();
$packs_count = 1;
foreach ($products as $product){
   while ($product['quantity'] != 0) {
        $pack[$packs_count]['weight'] = $pack[$packs_count]['weight'] +$product['weight'];
        if($pack[$packs_count]['weight'] >$max_weight){
            $pack[$packs_count]['weight'] = $pack[$packs_count]['weight'] - $product['weight'];
            $packs_count++;
         }
         $product['quantity']--;
 }
}
```

The code fails to get the last package right.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @gnat I updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: @gnat Well, I was confused where to ask. Thank you for the link. I hope one of the administrators would move the question to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using this code in PHP, Any additional thoughts would be great. Thanks anyway.

```
 $products = array(
    array('weight'=> 4, 'quantity' => 5),
    array('weight'=> 8, 'quantity' => 3),
);
$max_weight = 22;
$packs = array();
$packs_count = 1;

foreach ($products as $product){
   while ($product['quantity'] != 0) {
       $pack[$packs_count]['weight'] = $pack[$packs_count]['weight'] +$product['weight'];
        if($pack[$packs_count]['weight'] > $max_weight){
            $pack[$packs_count]['weight'] = $pack[$packs_count]['weight'] - $product['weight'];
            $packs_count++;
            $pack[$packs_count]['weight'] = $product['weight'];

        }
        $product['quantity']--;
   }
}

 print_r($pack);
```

Answer (score 0):

What your are trying to achieve is not fully clear to me. I'll make the assumption that you are trying to minimise the total number of packages created by the algorithm. If it is indeed the case what you are trying to solve is a [Bin Packing Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). This algorithm is NP-hard, however there are simple heuristics that behaves (probably) better than the one that you propose. For example the first fit decreasing algorithm which is going to consist of sorting the items from the biggest to the smallest and inserting them in the first bin in which they fit (creating a new bin if none of the existing one has enough remaining capacity)